# How to install a custom java look & feel which can be accessed through UIManager?

Tags: java, uimanager

I added a custom look & feel jar to jre folder. I can then access using the following:

```
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("customLAF");
```

Before run time, Is it possible to install the l&f so as to access using the following:

```
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("customLF".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
```